# Proguard gradle task taking immense time

Tags: android, gradle, build, proguard, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Recently migrated to Gradle kotlin DSL and now proguarded builds are taking a lot of time, around 30 minutes. Tried scanning the build, and this is the message I received on the proguard task:

`app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForStageInternal`

```
Output property 'otherFileOutputs.otherFileOutput1' file app/build/outputs/mapping/stage/internal/mapping.txt has been removed.
Output property 'otherFileOutputs.otherFileOutput2' file app/build/outputs/mapping/stage/internal/seeds.txt has been removed.
Output property 'otherFileOutputs.otherFileOutput3' file app/build/outputs/mapping/stage/internal/usage.txt has been removed.
```

I am certain I am not removing these files manually and cannot understand how or which task is removing them, causing them to be regenerated all over again.

Also another thing I noticed is that a file called `resources.txt` is not being generated as opposed to my previous builds using groovy dsl for gradle.